# hyperledger fabric samples balance transfer When I enroll user is success, but it's return result secret filed is null

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I try to enroll an user in balance transfer samples, But it's return result secret field is null. I can't find solution from rocket chat and google and stackoverflow. Can someone help me? Thanks very much.
I exec this code
 "curl -s -X POST http://localhost:4000/users -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'username=Jim&orgName=Org1'"
And the return result is:

---

"
{ 
  "success":true,
  **"secret":""**,
  "message":"Jim enrolled Successfully",
  "token":"tokenString"
 }
"

---

And I expect the result is:

---

"
{
  "success": true,
  **"secret": "RaxhMgevgJcm"**,
  "message": "Jim enrolled Successfully",
  "token": "tokenString"
}
"

---

I can't find the reason why after I enrolled the user, the result's secret field is null. I hope it have the value.

Comment: The hyperledger fabric version is release-1.1

Comment: Do not provide images of code and output. Provide a well formatted code sample and error message with details on what results you expect. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: sorry, It's my fault. I should read the SO guidelines before posting. Thank you for your reminder. I will correct my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the current balance transfer sample app described in this [JIRA issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-9216). A patch has been submitted, but my understanding is that there's actually a bug in the SDK code that will be addressed separately.

Comment: oh oh. It turns out so. I think this may be the reason. Thank you